# `sjPlot::tab_df()`--how to set the number of decimal places?

Tags: r, sjplot

I'm trying to use `sjPlot` to produce a table of Descriptive Statistics, and I am trying to set the number of digits after the decimal point.

This is what I've tried (reproducible example below):

```
library(sjPlot)
library(sjmisc)

tab_df(mtcars, digits = 1)

descr(mtcars) %>% 
  tab_df(digits = 1)
```

In both cases, I'm still getting many digits trailing after the decimal point.

[image]

## Edit:

The code below from Daniel produces close to the result I'm looking for, but you can still see that trailing zeros are being rounded off, so not all numbers are to two decimal places.

```
library(sjPlot)
library(sjmisc)

tab_df(mtcars, digits = 1)

descr(mtcars) %>% 
  tab_df(digits = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick workaround would be using `sjmisc::round_num()`:

```r
library(sjPlot)
library(sjmisc)

tab_df(mtcars, digits = 1)

descr(mtcars) %>% 
  round_num(2) %>% 
  tab_df()
```

Comment: This is very helpful. I've shown the output that it produces in my edited question above--there's still the issue of trailing zeros being rounded off. Would you know of an easy workaround?

Comment: You could work with `sprintf("%.2f")` or so, which is also not much effort, but I think in this case it's easier to implement that feature directly in `tab_df()`. I'll keep you updated once this feature is available.

Comment: I have added a `digits`-option to `tab_df()`. You can install from [sjPlot-GitHub](https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot), e.g. `devtools::install_github("strengejacke/sjPlot")`. Then your initial example should work.

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry to ask such a basic question next, but I've tried googling and debugging: I've run `> devtools::install_github("strengejacke/sjPlot", force = TRUE)`, but R still gives me a message `building ‘sjPlot_2.7.0.9000.tar.gz’`, i.e. I believe it's still the previous version, because the `digits` -option doesn't come up when I Tab in R Studio.

Comment: The version number is ok, that indicates the development-version. A bit strange, though, because there is [the digits-argument](https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/blob/master/R/html_print.R#L94) in `tab_df()` from the GitHub version.

Comment: for anyone reading this in the future, what fixed it for me was: `remove.packages("sjPlot")`, then `devtools::install_github("strengejacke/sjPlot")`. Thank you so much @daniel, it works so well!